# Break ranges between two columns into rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CODE](
    [BEG] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [END] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [EFF_BEG] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

Insert into CODE select 'H0411', 'H0413', '01/01/2015'
Insert into CODE select 'J090', 'J093', '01/01/2015'
```

I want to get the list of all codes within the BEG and END like below

```
Instance
-------
H0411
H0412
H0413
J090
J091
J092
J093
```

i have something like below but it wont work on varchar column

```
WITH number_cte (n)
AS (
    SELECT n
    FROM (
        SELECT 0 n
        ) m

    UNION ALL

    SELECT n + 1 n
    FROM number_cte
    WHERE n < 2400
    )
SELECT BEG+n instance
    ,EFF_BEG
FROM CODE
JOIN number_cte ON BEG + n BETWEEN BEG
        AND END
WHERE BEG + n - 100 * floor((BEG + n) / 100) BETWEEN 0
        AND 59
ORDER BY 1
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 2401)
```

Any solution to this? Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to do that inside SQL? Without an explicitly good reason, do that in the app layer with proper tools

Comment: Use SUBSTRING to remove the leading character, CAST to an INT, do the recursive query and CAST to a CHAR again and add the 1st character back.

Comment: @dnoeth - not *entirely* accurate. You'd loose the leading zero after the character, and then the question, what should happen to J090 -> J120, or J990 -> J1010...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is through `Numbers` table or CTE which you can join to `CODE` table like this:

```
WITH NUMBERS AS ( -- change limit if needed
  SELECT TOP 10000 row_number() over(order by t1.number) as Number
  FROM master..spt_values t1 
    CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2),
CODE_SPLIT AS
( SELECT 
    BEG, [END],
    SUBSTRING(BEG, 1, PATINDEX('%[1-9]%', BEG)-1) as FirstChars,
    CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(BEG, 2, LEN(BEG) - 1)) as BegInt,
    CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING([END], 2, LEN([END]) - 1)) as EndInt
  FROM [dbo].[CODE]
)
SELECT c.*,
 c.FirstChars + CAST(n.Number as VARCHAR) as Result
FROM 
 CODE_SPLIT c INNER JOIN 
 NUMBERS n ON n.Number BETWEEN BegInt AND EndInt;
```

I have left all the fields in the output for validation, results are in `Result` column.

The main assumption that was made is that codes consist of two parts with corresponding order:

- Single non-numeric character;
- Number that can have leading zeros.

To create permanent `Numbers` table you can use this code:

```
CREATE TABLE NumbersTest (Number  int  not null)  
INSERT INTO NumbersTest(Number)
SELECT TOP 10000 row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
FROM master..spt_values t1 
    CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2;
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c16f5/3) for working code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and comments

Comment: np, also pay attention to 10000 limit hardcoded in the numbers